# Should I limit redemption of coupon by ip address only or is this not reliable?

Tags: security, ip

My site allows all users to redeem a coupon. However membership is free to the site. How I structure my redemption system to best discourage people from creating many free accounts to redeem many coupons?

I was thinking of only allowing one redemption per ip per week. Is this reliable? What is the most reliable way?

Answer (score 2):

Using IP is generally not great as, depending in the customer ISP, it might not be unique to the individual customer.  You might be better off looking at [cookies for tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Tracking) (and expire them after a week).

Answer (score 1):

Terrible idea. Give it up.

Here's just a few reasons:

- Everyone who works in the same office probably shares an IP.
- Everyone who lives in the same house probably shares an IP.
- Everyone who comes online through the wifi in that starbucks down the road, probably shares an IP.
- Home networks where the router is set to use DHCP will get a different IP address every time it is bounced.
- Users on cellphone networks will most likely be routed via a pool of proxy servers and can have different IPs even during the same session.

Comment: 'Everyone who lives in the same house probably shares an IP.' I doubt that. It depends on the way the access is provided.

Comment: I agree completely that there could be legitimate users who may get delayed from redeeming their coupon this way (and have to wait out the time buffer), but the goal is to thwart the abusive use of the coupon system. So at the very worst legit users will be DELAYED. Do you have any recommendations for a better system?